# Can I attach a freestanding deck to concrete block garage wall?

Tags: deck, joists, cinderblock, ledger

I'm certain you can't attach a ledger to cinder block that is why the deck is going to be free standing. However, I would like to know if the deck could somehow be secured to the garage. Kind of like what a ledger board does only without joist hangers as it is free standing.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This sounds like a XY problem. The deck does not need to be freestanding. A ledger board can be attached directly to the structure using the appropriate concrete anchors. There are 2 common methods. The first is to use a sleeve anchor. You can also epoxy threaded rod into the wall as well.

Comment: I was told by the local inspector that a cinder block wall can not support the weight of a deck as they are hollow and that it had to be free standing. Is this incorrect?

Comment: You'd typically do a core-fill or some other reinforcement. However, if done right the block would carry the load just fine. It's a matter of meeting local codes.

Comment: So now I wonder what your question is. Are you asking whether it's possible, whether the inspector is wrong about local codes, or how you can skirt the codes?

Comment: I agree with Isherwood. If the wall is filled (all the foundation work I have seen/ done has been) the wall should be fine with a ledger. I would verify this and double check with the inspector. (in my area the walls have re bar in every other hole and filled).

Comment: I doubt that the already fully built garage has the cores filled and rebar in them (I'm just not sure) The question is, if I build the deck free standing, How can I secure the deck against the garage. Or should I even be concerned with this?

Answer (score 2):

The fact is that your deck's weight load must be carried underneath it and not using the cinder blocks supporting your garage.  That does not limit you from attaching it to the garage to provide horizontal stability and to keep movements in unison.

You would simply need to bolt in a faux ledger to the cinder blocks.  Make sure that you have at least two posts close to the garage that you are showing as the weight bearing points for that wall.  Any good inspector should realize this.

Note though your garage has been there for X amount of time and assuming it was made right, it probably isn't moving much.  Now build a deck and drop 4-8 posts in the ground - make sure that you are adequately putting these well below frost line and that they are big enough.  By attaching it to the cinder blocks there is a chance that your posts could cause upheaval on the garage wall. - especially with cinder blocks.

Comment: I'm new to the term Faux Ledger. Can you explain what this is. Is it a special material?

Comment: A ledger holds up a side of a deck.  It is a load point a faux (fake) ledger is just attached to the structure but provides no vertical structural relief.